# Thunderbolt, with other stuff

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, mazes

Find 1) the correct path through the maze and 2) a six-letter thematic answer.

[image: thunderbolt]

Text version:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blood | Father | Metal | Too strong |
| Data storage device | Capital's inlet | Capital | Code |
| Polar climate | US soap opera | Radiation | Road |
| Radiation | Schooling | Weather | Thunderbolt |

Any adjacent cells (two cells that share a side) are connected. Additionally, each of the four corner cells are connected to the outside of the grid. These are the only connecting paths that exist.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To pass through the maze, take the following route:

> (Enter top left) - Blood - Data storage device - Polar climate - US soap opera - Capital's inlet - Capital - Metal - Too strong - Code - Road - Radiation - Weather - Thunderbolt - (Exit bottom right)
>
>  (This is presented diagrammatically in a later spoiler, fear not...)

The reasoning behind this is that...

> ...every phrase in the maze can be represented by *a pair of letters*. Specifically, though, most of them can be represented by **two consecutive letters of the English alphabet**. And even more specifically, it is possible to plot a route through the maze whereby the entire English alphabet can be spelled out in order by these letter pairs!
>
>  **AB** "Blood" = a [blood group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABO_blood_group_system);
>  **CD** "Data storage device" = compact disc;
>  **EF** "Polar climate" = represents an 'ice cap climate' in the [Köppen climate classification system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6ppen_climate_classification#:%7E:text=EF%20%3D%20Ice%20cap%20climate%3B%20eternal,C%20(32%20%C2%B0F).);
>  **GH** "US soap opera" = [*General Hospital*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Hospital);
>  **IJ** "Capital's inlet" = a [body of water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IJ_(Amsterdam)) in Amsterdam, capital of the Netherlands;
>  **KL** "Capital" = Kuala Lumpur, capital of Malaysia;
>  **MN** "Metal" = Manganese (chemical symbol 'Mn');
>  **OP** "Too strong" = 'Over-powered';
>  **QR** "Code" = QR code;
>  **ST** "Road" = an abbreviation of 'street';
>  **UV** "Radiation" = Ultra-Violet;
>  **WX** "Weather" = Morse code shorthand for '[Weather](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WX)';
>  **YZ** "Thunderbolt" = Name of [The Thunderbolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_(DC_Comics)) in DC Comics.

You can see this most easily in an image:

> [image: Route through the maze]

Note that three rooms are unvisited...

> ...and that the phrases in each of these can also be represented by a pair of letters, just not alphabetically-adjacent-and-ordered ones:
>
>  **PA** "Father" = a nickname for one's dad;
>  **IR** "Radiation" = Infra-Red;
>  **ED** "Schooling" = Abbreviation for 'EDucation'.
>
>  Putting these together in order from top-to-bottom, left-to-right spells out **PAIRED** - the hidden six-letter thematic answer, since this puzzle is all about *pairs of letters*!

Comment: Yes, that's the one. rot13(Gur gvgyr znl nyfb freir nf n uvag/pbasvezngvba orpnhfr bs gur svefg yrggref bs rnpu jbeq gurer.) How did you break into the puzzle? I'm curious as usual.

Comment: @oAlt Ha, I hadn't spotted the acronym there :) My 'in' was that as I thought around things that could be synonyms of the phrases, I came up with suggestions for 'Radiation', 'Too strong' and 'Road' that fitted a certain pattern. Noticing that 'Road' and 'Radiation' were adjacent gave me a theory, and finding that 'Code' fitted neatly in between confirmed it - I had a solid chain! 'Metal' was then forced, I quickly cracked 'Blood', 'Data storage device' and Capital' and I then filled in the gaps with the help of the pattern and confirmatory Wikipedia searches. A satisfying puzzle to solve :)